# How to refresh page after f:actionlistener event

Tags: jsf, actionlistener

Working with JSF, I have a `<ux:confirm>` tag, which has a confirm button. When clicked it triggers a actionListenerEvent. The page and the objects in the faces context are updated, however I have a bootstrap accordion which is not updated. A solution would be refreshing the page, which is my question.

```
<ux:confirm
    ok="#{message.get('Label.Sim')}"
    ajax="true"
    render="form-consulta"
    cancel="#{message.get('Label.Nao')}"
    title="#{message.get('Label.Excluir')}"
    message="#{message.get('Msg.DesejaExcluirRegistro')}"
    >

    <f:actionListener 
      for="onOkClick" 
      binding="#{bean.excluir()}" 
       />
</ux:confirm>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved by just adding a JavaScript function on the ajax event and also calling somewhat a template method using javascript.

```css
<f:ajax
 render="#{cc.attrs.render}"
 disabled="#{not cc.attrs.ajax}"
 onevent="onEventConfirm"
 />
```

```html
function onEventConfirm(data) {
       
 App.ajax.onEvent(App.view.block, null, null, App.view.unblock);
 
 var status = data.status;

 switch (status) {
 
  case "complete":
   if(shouldRefreshAfterConfirmation)
    this.location.reload();
    break;
    
 }
}
```